# How to update my db objects without any order?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Image situation, I have my application for personal calendar. There is a model inside which holds days and just for my application day could be a thing which can be 48h long. In order to have everything ok, my days can not overlap each other - there is exclusion constraint in db.

So my problem is when I am trying to update my calendar to new timezone, my days overlap each other. For example first day start from 01:00 to 23:00 15 March, second day is from 00:03 to 23:30 16 March, when we switch timezone +-3h it fails:

```py
    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ExclusionViolation) conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "days_timerange_user_id_excl"
E       DETAIL:  Key (timerange, user_id)=(["2014-03-15 22:45:00+00","2014-03-16 11:50:00+00"), 739) conflicts with existing key (timerange, user_id)=(["2014-03-16 04:00:00+00","2014-03-16 10:00:00+00"), 739).
E        [SQL: 'UPDATE days SET timerange=%(timerange)s WHERE days.id = %(days_id)s'] [parameters: {'timerange': MutableDateTimeTZRange(datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 15, 12, 45, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Tahiti')), datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 16, 1, 50, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Tahiti')), '[)'), 'days_id': 858}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

My function which is doing that is:

```py
# Days
for i in user.days[::direction]:
   i.timerange = change_tz_timerange(i.timerange, user.timezone, timezone)
   self.request.dbsession.flush()
```

I tried switching directions but it doesn't matter when timezone difference is big enough.

under `change_tz_timerange` you can see:

```py
def change_tz_timerange(timerange, old_tz, new_tz):
    return DateTimeTZRange(
                replace_tz(timerange.lower, old_tz, new_tz),
                replace_tz(timerange.upper, old_tz, new_tz),
                '[)'
            )
```

and `replace_tz`:

```py
def replace_tz(dt, old_timezone, new_timezone):
    old_tz = pytz.timezone(old_timezone)
    dt = dt.astimezone(old_tz)
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
    return arrow.get(dt, new_timezone).datetime
```

Is there a way to update them all in one time? 
or to "delete" them during updating process? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be simply to change the constraint to be deferred. Then it is not checked as part of the statement, but right before the end of the transaction.

```
ALTER TABLE days
   ALTER CONSTRAINT days_timerange_user_id_excl
      DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Then by the time the constraint is validated, the table will be consistent again.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you!